# task.Wait causing a long pause in my GUI thread

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have this code:

```
        public async Task<string> Solve(List<List<Node>> nodeList)
    {
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count(); i++)
        {
            int taskNo = i;
            Task<List<Node>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew((x) =>
            {
                List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>(nodeList[i]);
                Calculate(nodes);
                return nodes;
            }, taskNo);

            task.Wait();
            taskList.Add(task);

        }

        Task<string> r = BuildReport(taskList);

        return r;
    }
```

This method is being called by another method on my UI thread.
This method causes my UI thread to pause and makes the window unresponsive for 20-50 seconds.  I have a feeling the task.Wait is causing this pause.  How could I modify this method so that this won't happen.  If I do not have the task.Wait the taskList doesn't get the proper tasks in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe call your task from another thread than the UI thread ?

Comment: Are you `await`ing this from the caller?

Comment: Please add the calling code for the 'Solve' task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `Wait` your tasks. Use `await Task.WhenAll(taskList);` Your code will be similar to this:

```
public async Task<string> Solve(List<List<Node>> nodeList)
{
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count(); i++)
    {
        int taskNo = i;
        Task<List<Node>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew((x) =>
        {
            List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>(nodeList[taskNo]); //replace i with taskNo
            Calculate(nodes);
            return nodes;
        }, taskNo);

        // remove Wait
        taskList.Add(task);

    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList); //Add this line
    Task<string> r = BuildReport(taskList);

    return r;
}
```

In your current code, you create a task and then wait for it to finish. This isn't much different than running your code sequentially. Using `Task.WhenAll` here has 2 advantages. a) Your tasks will run in parallel b) Since we are *awaiting* it, your UI will not be blocked.

Comment: Ahh I was so close.  That worked.  The UI is still a bit herky jerky still...but I think I can live with that.  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Also, with `async-.await` use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx